# How do I open "apt" links in Firefox (in Lubuntu)?

Tags: apt, firefox, software-center, lubuntu

Many answers on Ask Ubuntu direct to links like [this](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/goldendict) that in Xubuntu opened in Ubuntu Software Center. In Lubuntu I get this error message:

[image]

In Firefox-Preferences/Applications cannot see something resembling to `apt` to associate to a program etc.

[image]

[image]

Opening the same link in Chromium or Opera I get:

[image]

Clicking "I'm running Ubuntu" results in an error message like in Firefox.

What's the remedy? Can I install Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: use apt://skype for example and install USC - Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is install the (Ubuntu) Software Center in Lubuntu.

Open a terminal, and type `sudo apt-get install software-center`. Then, the first time you click on a APT link in Firefox should give you the below popup, after which such links should open automatically:

[image]

[image]

---

Beside Ubuntu Software Center, a much lighter application (`AptUrl`) can be used to handle "apt://" protocol/links: see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/183536/47206) to a related question.

Comment: well, thnx, i already got that a few sec before. but i have a new question: http://askubuntu.com/q/183517/47206

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that since I was already typing :) I'm looking at the other question.

Comment: If he is on 12.04, is it not possible to use Lubuntu software-center instead?

Comment: LSC does not support the apt handler. (notice there are no MimeType lines in [lsc.desktop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1183307/))

Comment: Considering that Ubuntu 13.10 software center doesn't have this functionality anymore by default, I doubt this will work.

Comment: I cannot change the apt link association once it's fixed... any idea?

Answer (score 13):

Point the select application to:

```
/usr/bin/apturl
```

This sould solve the problem.

Don't forget to check "Remember".

Comment: Use the command `sudo apt install apturl-common` to install the apturl tool if not already installed, then reload the apt: page

Comment: I cannot change the apt link association once I clicked "remember", any idea how to undo it???

Answer (score 4):

The issue is solved after installing Ubuntu Software Center, which was **not** installed.

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Now, after opening that link in Firefox, it offers the normal option to open that link in Ubuntu Software Center, and to remember that option. Also, following this, `apt` appears in the list from Firefox' Preferences/Applications:

[image: Preferences/Applications Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what [Firefox support page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-how-firefox-handles-different-file-types) says about this:

> The Applications panel has limited functionality for editing. You can
>   change the action for an existing file type but you cannot add or
>   remove file types. Entries are added automatically when you download
>   files and select actions for them.

However, in your case you can try modifying you `~/.mozilla/firefox/\*\*\*\*.default/mimeTypes.rdf`. Here is a link to mine: http://pastebin.com/4HhX6xSE

Comment: see my question text: `In Firefox-Preferences/Applications cannot see something resembling to apt to associate to a program`. now i added images. also: `Can I install Ubuntu Software Center?`. i guess i can, and i'll try to

Comment: up-vote for your responsiveness thnx, but you see i got the simplest way. the problem was simple: Lubuntu doesn't come with `Ubuntu Software Center`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in lubuntu 14.04 by opening the link using the path /usr/bin/apturl
I changed it in my firefox preferences for future use.