# Can I use other tool than Ubuntu Software Center to open apt links?

Tags: apt, software-center, lubuntu

Without *Ubuntu Software Center* in Lubuntu I was unable to edit opening *apt* links in any program in Firefox (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/183505/47206)). After installing *Ubuntu Software Center*, that problem is solved, but could I use another program instead of *Ubuntu Software Center* for the same purpose? I find it too heavy, and to install I prefer the **Terminal**, *gdebi*, *Lubuntu Software Center* or the *Synaptic*.

(Now that I have the *apt* option in Firefox/Preferences/Applications, I try to change  *Ubuntu Software Center* to *Lubuntu Software Center* but this does not change the option.)

Comment: What happens when you click the link? it should take you to the online software center and when you click on the button (orange) you should be a dialog box trying to install

Comment: as i already have  Ubuntu Software Center installed the link opens that program as a means of installing. i was looking for other programs than  Ubuntu Software Center. why not the terminal opening instead of  Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Neither gDebi, Synaptic or Lubuntu Software Center support handling the "apt://" protocol/links.
- But a very simple graphical `apt-get`-type installer called [*AptURL*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) does.

  - Install it with `sudo apt-get install apturl`
  - Set Firefox Preferences to "Always Ask" for *apt*
  - Click on a link, and select AptURL:

  [image]

  - And the window will pop open:

  [image]

  - Installation will take place using a lightweight gDebi-style frontend
- The other option is to use a custom script such as [green7's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/183528/58612)
- But to be browser-independent, what you really need is:

  1. A `.desktop` file for your script/application, indicating that it handles the `x-scheme-handler/apt` protocol (see `MimeType=` lines in [aptURL.desktop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1183255), [ubuntu-software-center.desktop](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1183256))
  2. And you can set the default by modifying the `defaults.list` file in `/usr/share/applications/`

Answer (score 5):

You can change the *Action* in *Preferences* > *Applications* from `Ubuntu Software Center` to this simple shell script.

```
#! /bin/bash

toInstall="$@"
toInstall=${toInstall#*:}
lxterm -e "sudo apt-get install $toInstall; read"
```

Save this to some file, say `aptFirefox.sh`, and make it executable by running:

```
chmod +x /path/to/aptFirefox.sh
```

Now you can replace `Ubuntu Software Center` with `aptFirefox.sh`.

[image]

Now whenever you click on any `apt` link, it will show a terminal window asking for your password.

[image]

After you correctly enter your password, it will install the package.

[image]

**Note** that you can use `xterm` in place of `lxterm`.

Comment: as i use Firefox, your answer is perfect to me but i have set as definitive izx's answer as it has a more general application. merging the 2 answers into one would be great.