# What to choose as application to launch Brightness-Controller?

Tags: lubuntu, software-installation, brightness

I'm new in *ubuntu. I'm using lubuntu 14.04. When I'm trying to download [Brightness Controller](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trusty/brightness-controller/) it is saying

> This link needs to be open with an application.

Which application to choose? Actually I'm not getting *Brightness Controller* in Lubuntu Software Center. That's why I've to download it like this. Is there any way?

Comment: Have you tried this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183505/how-do-i-open-apt-links-in-firefox-on-lubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Choose Software-Center from `/usr/bin/software-center`

Answer (score 1):

download latest source code from here:
[Brightness Controler](https://codeload.github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/zip/master)

after extracting,
in terminal install this:`sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0`
now from "SRC" folder run "brightness.py"!

Alternatively, you can install it using the PPA with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

You can control brightness using its slider.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/thumbnail/225x170/appmedia/2014/01/brightness-controller_mac2_1.png))</sub>

Comment: I just had to restart my comp because I got a black screen because of that script. I accidentally moved it to left and screen got black, I did not see anything.